# Undefined Index: Array in Name parameter of setCookie

Tags: php, setcookie, undefined-index

I know that Undefined Index questions have been asked and answered before. But please humor me for a second. I couldn't find the answer to this specific case. (And an unusual case it is.)

This works without a problem...

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset (  $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
}

$expiry = time()+60*60*9000;
setcookie('loggedin', 'foo', $expiry);

echo "sessionvalue " . $_SESSION['loggedin'] . '<br>';
echo "cookievalue " . $_COOKIE['loggedin'] . '<br>';

?>
```

...producing this output

```
sessionvalue 1
cookievalue foo
```

However, when I change the Name parameter in the setCookie to an array like so:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if ( ! isset (  $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = FALSE;
  }

  $expiry = time()+60*60*9000;
  setcookie('cookievalue[loggedin]', 'foo', $expiry);

  echo "sessionvalue " . $_SESSION['loggedin'] . '<br>';
  echo "cookievalue " . $_COOKIE['cookievalue[loggedin]'] . '<br>';

?>
```

I get the Undefined Index notice like so:

```
sessionvalue 1

Notice: Undefined index: cookievalue[loggedin] in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/simpleauth/headersessioncookie.php on line 13
cookievalue
```

What can I declare, and how, to avoid the "Notice" in the second case?

Comment: Try `echo "cookievalue " . $_COOKIE['cookievalue']['loggedin'] . '<br>';`

Comment: @V4KK4R that should work so long as PHP 5.4

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php look at example #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
echo "cookievalue " . $_COOKIE['cookievalue[loggedin]'] . '<br>';
```

should be

```php
echo "cookievalue " . $_COOKIE['cookievalue']['loggedin'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: Did you just copy paste what the comment of @V4KK4R says? :)

Comment: @G.Samaras Huh, I didn't notice.  Next time I'll be sure to read all of the comments before hand.  Thanks for pointing that out!